# Get the header of my table fixed

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to get the header of my table fixed, so it could be always visible while scrolling down. The height of my table would be fixed to 500 px.
Here is a plunkr:
[enter link description here](http://plnkr.co/edit/keuJ2suH8Vj9iCgpzXzg?p=preview)

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th style="text-align:center">Produit</th>
          <th style="text-align:center">Emballage</th>
          <th style="text-align:center">Certificat Fourn.</th>
          <th style="text-align:center">Marque</th>
          <th style="text-align:center">Catégorie</th>
          <th style="text-align:center">Calibre</th>
          <th style="text-align:center" colspan="3">20/03</th>
          <th style="text-align:center" colspan="3">21/03</th>
          <th style="text-align:center" colspan="3">22/03</th>
          <th style="text-align:center" colspan="3">23/03</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="6"></th>
        <th>Rsr</th>
        <th>Arr</th>
        <th>Dsp</th>
        <th>Rsr</th>
        <th>Arr</th>
        <th>Dsp</th>
        <th>Rsr</th>
        <th>Arr</th>
        <th>Dsp</th>
        <th>Rsr</th>
        <th>Arr</th>
        <th>Dsp</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="planning in data">
          <td style="text-align:center">
              {{planning.produit}}
          </td>
          <td style="text-align:center">                                    
              {{planning.emballage}}
          </td>
          <td style="text-align:center">                                    
              {{planning.certificatFournisseur}}
          </td>
          ...

          <td style="text-align:center">
              {{planning.dispJ4}}
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have looked over the net, but I didn"t find any nice solution.
Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to split your table to one with headers and a second one with data. Then add javascript that on scroll (detect if the position of your header table are near the 0 of screen and if yes then add css style for your header table -> `position:fixed top:0px ;`
you will also have a reverse javascript for removing position: fixed when viewer scroll up.

### EDIT

If you dont care to lose table from page you can juse use 2 tables (header and content) put content's table's height = 500px - header's table's height and for content's table css `overflow:scroll`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my knowledge in javascript is to small to traduce in code what you just said...;)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that works pretty well on one of my tables.
I have tried to apply it to another table but I am getting differences between td width and th width. I don't know why, even if I set the same width to each one of them.

If anyone can explain to me the reason why...
Thanks!
Plunkr :
http://plnkr.co/edit/kDxIYzmO6onqqZcZIURc?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="font-size:11px;table-layout: fixed; margin-bottom:0px">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center;width:168px">Fournisseur</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;width:148px">Désignation</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;width:81px">Date</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;width:53px">Colis</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;width:53px">Brut</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;width:53px">Tare</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;width:78px">Poids net</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;width:58px">Pièces</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;width:68px">Palette</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;width:53px">Valo</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;width:98px">Prix unit ht</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;width:58px">H.T.</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;width:58px">Tva</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
      <div class="wrap_scrollable">
        <div class="scrollable">
          <table class="table table-bordered" style="font-size:11px;table-layout: fixed">
            <tbody>
              <!-- ngRepeat: frais in listeFrais -->
              <tr >
                <td style="text-align:center;width:168px;word-wrap: break-word" class="ng-binding">ALIMEA</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;width:148px;word-wrap: break-word" class="ng-binding">Triage</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;width:81px;word-wrap: break-word" class="ng-binding">2015-04-01</td>
                ...
               <td style="text-align:center;width:58px;word-wrap: break-word" class="ng-binding">-50</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;width:58px;word-wrap: break-word" class="ng-binding">0</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- end ngRepeat: frais in listeFrais -->
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;width:168px;word-wrap: break-word" class="ng-binding">ALBA BIO COOP</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;width:148px;word-wrap: break-word" class="ng-binding">Triage</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;width:81px;word-wrap: break-word" class="ng-binding">2015-04-01</td>
                ...
                <td style="text-align:center;width:98px;word-wrap: break-word" class="ng-binding">2</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;width:58px;word-wrap: break-word" class="ng-binding">-20</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;width:58px;word-wrap: break-word" class="ng-binding">0</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- end ngRepeat: frais in listeFrais -->
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```